# How do i activate Lightning Desktop on winter16

Tags: lightning

I have a developer account with winter16. I can t seem to find a way to activate the new Lightning Desktop UI.

Can anyone suggest how this can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prady After looking around for a bit I signed up for a winter 16 pre-release 
dev org from the link below

https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-winter16-47984592.jsp

Look at e.weetch answer:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BUmLIAW

I was able to enable lightning when I signed up using the above link

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe its only available in the new pre release dev orgs requested thru [this link](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-winter16.jsp)  [ I am not sure if its available in all Winter 16 developer orgs.. ]

When you login to the new Winter 16 sandbox / dev orgs, you will see the new "Lightning Experience" menu item in the left navigation menu.

[image]

When you click on that, you will see the options to enable the new lightning ui and the permissions to specify which users can use it

[image]

Comment: I did use the link the create a developer account. The dev account is with winter16 but i cant find the Lightning Experience link. Will try out a enterprise trial from that link and see if that brings up that link

Comment: did u try changing the url to one/one.app and see if it worked ?.. eg :   https://gs0.lightning.force.com/one/one.app

Comment: no luck for me too, I created both enterprise and developer accounts. Lightning is not getting enabled by default

Comment: Yup.. unfortunately these dont work

Comment: @VamsiKrishna are you on a developer org (or) is this screenshot from some sandbox

Comment: it's from a pre release dev org created from the link I shared